# Range not Found Error on for Loop in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, types

I'm looking to create templates using GAS -- all I need is to copy and paste variables into designated cells, push the data, then move to the next.

I had my script working great for a single template (the first set of variables).  I tried to set up a loop, and now I'm hitting a "Range not found" error I'm going crazy trying to figure out.

I had it working copying and pasting the variables out and generating the template, but struggling to get it to move to the next cell in each column.

I made a range for each column where the script should loop through, meaning:

Row 2 Col A, Row 2 Col B, Row 2 Col C, Row 2 Col D each go through the loop (variables get pasted, sheet gets created, etc), then we move onto Row 3 Col A, Row 2 Col B, so on so forth.

```
function CreateTemplates() {
   var templatesNeeded = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Test');            
   var rundownSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Exclusive Template Creation');
   var tabname = templatesNeeded.getRange('A2').getValue();
   var pasteTemplate = rundownSheet.getRange('e1:l150').getValues();

    const row = 2;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Test');
  const rows = sheet.getLastRow() - row + 1;
  const range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, rows, 1);
  const values = range.getValues().flat();

 const dateRange = sheet.getRange(row, 2, rows, 1);
  const dateValues = dateRange.getValues().flat();


   const gameRange = sheet.getRange(row, 3, rows, 1);
  const gameValues = gameRange.getValues().flat();


   const typeRange = sheet.getRange(row, 4, rows, 1);
  const typeValues = typeRange.getValues().flat();

     const broadcastRange = sheet.getRange(row, 5, rows, 1);
  const broadcastValues = broadcastRange.getValues().flat();

  const matches = {};
  values.forEach((value, i) => {
    if (value !== '') {

  
 rundownSheet.getRange('E3').setValue(templatesNeeded.getRange(values).getValue());
   rundownSheet.getRange('B1').setValue(templatesNeeded.getRange(dateValues).getValue());
   rundownSheet.getRange('B2').setValue(templatesNeeded.getRange(gameValues).getValue());
   rundownSheet.getRange('B3').setValue(templatesNeeded.getRange(typeValues).getValue());
rundownSheet.getRange('H2').setValue(templatesNeeded.getRange(broadcastValues).getValue());

 
     var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('16nn9mfSOpVbPZBsB_nwhRNRv4nYQblrS1GzAD4jgmoQ');

 var sheet = tss.getSheetByName('Single Template');


 sheet.copyTo(tss).setName(tabname);


 
// Logger.log(value)

  sheet.getRange(1,1,pasteTemplate.length,pasteTemplate[0].length).setValues(pasteTemplate);



Utilities.sleep(1000);
    }
  });
}
```

I think it's clearly a problem with how I created my ranges (or something with the loop).  Any thoughts are greatly, greatly appreciated.

Here's a test link where the code would be hosted:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WeBgyi8JVfC02rCIB0T1eEbbmtpaXYF16qM7MLIzqPs/edit#gid=0

Here's a test link where the code will be pushed to (templates will be created here):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16nn9mfSOpVbPZBsB_nwhRNRv4nYQblrS1GzAD4jgmoQ/edit#gid=804269175

Large improvement, but still hitting some errors.  Now, it's looping through and creating the tabs, but the setValues to actually move the data over doesn't seem to work. Thought it was a timing issue -  I added in utilities.sleep but still playing with it, with no luck yet.  Basically,  I want the variables to surface the data needed, that data to copy and paste to a template, then new variables, then new template:

```
   function createNewTemplates() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Test');
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Exclusive Template Creation');
  const sh1A2 = sh1.getRange('A2').getValue();
  const vs2 = sh2.getRange('e1:l150').getValues();
  const sr = 2;
  // const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Test');
  const vs1 = sh1.getRange(sr, 1, sh1.getLastRow() - sr + 1, 5).getValues();
  const tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('16nn9mfSOpVbPZBsB_nwhRNRv4nYQblrS1GzAD4jgmoQ');
  vs1.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (r[0] !== '') {
       Utilities.sleep(2000);
      sh2.getRange('E3').setValue(r[0]);
      sh2.getRange('B1').setValue(r[1]);
      sh2.getRange('B2').setValue(r[2]);
      sh2.getRange('B3').setValue(r[3]);
      sh2.getRange('H2').setValue(r[4]);
    
      let sh = tss.getSheetByName('Single Template');
      sh.copyTo(tss).setName(r[0]);
      let shnew = tss.getSheetByName(r[0]);
      Utilities.sleep(200);
      shnew.getRange(1, 1, vs2.length, vs2[0].length).setValues(vs2);
        
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: When I saw your script, I think that at `const broadcastRange = sheet.getRange(row, 45 rows, 1);`, an error occurs. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script. How about this? And about your error of `"Range not found"`, where does the error occur in your script?

Comment: @Tanaike huge catch, thank you - it's in as 5 on my computer, messed up pasting over.  Updated -- the error occurs at rows 33 and 29.  When I comment out row 33, it goes to 29 and 34. This led me to believe it has to do with looping through each column

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating it. When I saw your script, I think that an error occurs at `const broadcastRange = sheet.getRange(row, 5 rows, 1);`. I'm worried that you have miscopied your script.

Comment: @Tanaike apologies again. Silly me - I corrected the comma issue  - it's now pasted correctly, but still hitting the same error (Range not found)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that your script is the correct script. When I saw your script, I thought that when you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue, it will help to think of the current issue. Can you provide the sample script for correctly replicating your current issue?

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual Spreadsheet, in your script, the loop of `forEach`, `getRange(values)`, `getRange(dateValues)`,, are used. From your script, it seems that `values` is a 1-dimensional array. I think that the reason for your current issue might be this. And also, it seems that `dateValues` and other values are also a 1-dimensional array. But, I cannot know your Spreadsheet. So, I'm not sure whether your all issues will be resolved even when `values` is modified to `value`. I apologize for this.

Comment: The previous comment was posted while I was typing the following: The parameters of several expressions using `templatesNeeded.getRange` are wrong as the variables have being assigned Arrays but `SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange` methods should be a string, or 2, 3 or 4 numbers. Please work on creating a [mcve] and if you still need help, replace the current code by it. Don't forget to show the relevant parts of the spreadsheet and to include sample data, the expected result and the new textual error.

Comment: @Rubén For example, when a named range is used, `getRange(["sampleNamedRange"])` can be used, because `["sampleNamedRange"]` is converted to a string value. On the other hand, `getRange(["sampleNamedRange1", "sampleNamedRange2"])` cannot be used. An error like `Range not found` occurs. I thought that `values` might be `value` in OP's script. But, I'm not sure about OP's Spreadsheet. So, I thought that it is required to confirm OP's Spreadsheet.

Comment: Apologies on delay - I added in two sample sheets. Will continue looking to improve now, all of these thoughts are very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function createNewTemplates() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Test');
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Exclusive Template Creation');
  const vs2 = sh2.getRange('e1:l150').getValues();
  const sr = 2;
  const vs1 = sh1.getRange(sr, 1, sh1.getLastRow() - sr + 1, 5).getValues();
  const tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('16nn9mfSOpVbPZBsB_nwhRNRv4nYQblrS1GzAD4jgmoQ');
  let sh = tss.getSheetByName('Single Template');
  vs1.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (r[0] !== '') {
      sh2.getRange('E3').setValue(r[0]);
      sh2.getRange('B1').setValue(r[1]);
      sh2.getRange('B2').setValue(r[2]);
      sh2.getRange('B3').setValue(r[3]);
      sh2.getRange('H2').setValue(r[4]);
      let shnew = sh.copyTo(tss).setName(r[0]);
      shnew.getRange(1, 1, vs2.length, vs2[0].length).setValues(vs2);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: this is super clean and great, but a few things; I commented out line 8 because it was already defined, that got it working but it seems to not move to the 2nd row in the loop when pasting the values.  Meaning, the values in row 1 get pasted, but then instead of moving to row 2, it pastes row 1 again

Comment: I see this logic and would think it works.  I'm not worried about pushing to the other spreadsheet if that helps. would be huge even if we could replicate this action within the same sheet. meaning, generate the tab, set the values, then move to the next row paste those variables in, generate the tab, set the values, so on so forth. don't want that to be a confusing part - I can fix that later

Comment: Actually - I think I see the issue. It's taking the correct values, but the TABNAME is still hooked on the first row.  I think what I'll need to do is create a variable so the tabname is the value in the first column, then designate that when creating a new one.  This solution actually works I believe.  Amazing stuff, I just need to fix the next issue

Comment: Please share your final code in your question.  Maybe we can streamline it even more together.

Comment: Thanks @Cooper - this is a huge step.  I'm looping through and creating the tabs, but the data isn't moving over.  Going to keep tinkering - has to b esomething with the last line where we setValues of the old sheet.  It's like that part is not moving fast enough and then it moves to the next

Comment: I don't understand where you wish to copy to or from.  What is the source and what is the destination? Can you share a table of your data?

Comment: Apologies - so I want to loop through the "test" tab here. i want to place those variables into the designated cells on the exclusive template creation tab, so that the value in cell e6 changes. There should be a 1, 2, and 3, but when it's run - the templates are created but they all stay at 1. it doesnt look like the variables are being updated for some reason now :

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WeBgyi8JVfC02rCIB0T1eEbbmtpaXYF16qM7MLIzqPs/edit#gid=845002876

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16nn9mfSOpVbPZBsB_nwhRNRv4nYQblrS1GzAD4jgmoQ/edit#gid=661151347

Comment: basically, the variables draw a filter function which surfaces values. I want those values then to move over to the other tab. then i want the loop to plug in the next variables, thus surfacing the next data set to push to the next tab. not sure if that helps, still trying but really hitting a brick wall. im getting mixed results